# How does 1Password hook into this Dropbox screen?

Tags: ios, textbox, passwords, dropbox

This screenshot shows an 1Password UI in another app.

What API does 1Password use to hook into this?

[image]

Comment: I'd assume that's dropbox integrating one pass, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

This screenshot shows a part of the Dropbox app where the Dropbox app developers have integrated the 1Password App Extension. You can find information on the 1Password App Extension here:

https://blog.agilebits.com/2014/07/30/introducing-the-1password-app-extension-for-ios-8-apps/

It's available on GitHub here:

https://github.com/AgileBits/onepassword-app-extension